# How to see if a graph with two coloring has a monochromatic triangle?

Tags: computational-complexity, ramsey-theory, adjacency-matrix

Lets say you have an adjacency matrix version of K6 graph colored red or blue. How do you determine if there is a monochromatic triangle.

For example,

```
[[0 2 2 2 2 1]
 [2 0 2 2 2 1]
 [2 2 0 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 0 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2 0 1]
 [1 1 2 2 1 0]]
```

where "1" represents blue, "2" represents red, and "0" represents a no connections.

Comment: You are right. I changed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete graph with 6 vertices always has a monochromatic triangle, regardless of how you colour the edges. It's the first nontrivial case of [Ramsey's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem).

Take any vertex $v$, then there are five edges connected to $v$, so by the pigeonhole principle at least three of those edges have the same colour, e.g. let's say $vw$, $vx$ and $vy$ are the same colour, let's say red. Then there are two options:

- $wx$ or $xy$ or $wy$ is coloured red, which gives a red triangle when combined with the edges to $v$, or
- all of $wx$, $xy$ and $wy$ are blue, which means they together form a blue triangle.

Comment: I know that. I was just wondering how you would algorithmically show that for an adjacency matrix.

Comment: The proof of the fact itself provides an algorithm for finding a triangle, doesn't it?

Comment: If it's about algorithms specifically, this is known as the Clique Problem.

Comment: That's it. I was looking for a way to potentially expand it to a K4 or K5 coloring. Thanks!